# How do I use a custom stopwords filter in the Java Weka API?

Tags: classification, java, weka

I am using the Java Weka API to build a classification model. I can use the builtin stopwords filter. However, I need to use a custom filter for my problem. I do not know how to use a custom stopwords filter in the Java Weka API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector;
import weka.core.Instances;

Instances data = DataSource.read(".../document.txt"); //Your document .
filter.setInputFormat(data);
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
filter.setStopwords(new File(".../stopwords.txt")); //stop words file.
Instances data = Filter.useFilter(data,filter);
```

You can also read the following document for better understanding of the Weka API for Java.
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/

Comment: I appreciate your support. Thanks a lot. Your code and the link of the document really help me lot.

Answer (score 7):

First of all you have to prepare a text file for your custom stopwords. Then you can use the following code:

```
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector;

StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector(10000);
filter.setStopwords(new File(".../stopwords.txt"));
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I appreciate your support.

Comment: I am very new in Java weka-api programming. I do not understand clearly. Anyone please provide me little more elaborate answer. Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Please let us know which part do not you understand?